# Run an application in Background using Python in windows

Tags: python-3.x, simulator, circuit

```
path = "C:\\Users\\BIKRAM\\Documents\\LTspiceXVII\\NETLIST"
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.cir')):
    ltspice_path = r'C:\\Program Files\\LTC\\LTspiceXVII\\XVIIx64.exe'
    subprocess.Popen([ltspice_path, filename ])
```

I am running this code to execute multiples of .cir file into LTSpice application. But here LTSpice is opening for every .cir file. Is there any way to run all the file without opening UI of LTSpice?

Answer (score 0):

LTSpice simulation can be executed by batch process using command prompt

**LTSpice Help > Modes of Operation > Command Line Switches**

```
<path\of\program>XVIIx86.exe -b -Run file_name.cir
```

`-b` will execute `.cir` or `.asc` without opening LTSpice

This might help to add it to your multiple simulation programs